# Symfony sql request

Tags: sql, symfony

i'm performing an sql request, but in that request I would like to get all the field from the mission table...but if I write m.* inside the select...symfony told me the Mission entity doesn't have any * field. How can I translate that without getting all the field...because I got more or less 40 field in that table so...Thanks

```
$sql="SELECT v.id,v.codeVague, v.date_fin_ultime
          FROM McInvestigatorBundle:Vague v
                    INNER JOIN McInvestigatorBundle:Enquete e WITH e.vague_id = v.id
                    INNER JOIN McInvestigatorBundle:Mission m WITH m.id = e.mission_id
                    INNER JOIN McInvestigatorBundle:Contrat c WITH c.id = m.contrat
                    INNER JOIN McInvestigatorBundle:User u WITH u.enqueteur_id = e.enqueteur_id
                    INNER JOIN McInvestigatorBundle:PointDeVente p WITH p.id = e.pdv_id
          WHERE v.codeVague =".$wave_code."
                    AND e.type_id =".$type_id."
                    AND m.enqueteur_id=".$enq_id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try it with:

```
SELECT v.id,v.codeVague, v.date_fin_ultime, m
      FROM McInvestigatorBundle:Vague v
```

Comment: You saved me, i wasn't thinking about that a all. It works fine.